# Building a word game in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to build a word game in iphone. Basically, the user should be able to input a word to the screen using the keyboard(easy) and the app should be able to validate the word and suggest some other similar words (search a dictionary perhaps).

Is there a built in word dictionary on iphone that I can use. Any guidance to get this started would be much appreciated.

Comment: Similar in spelling or definition?

Comment: similar in spelling. Basically, starting with the first 2 letters or so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a dictionary built in on the iphone as far as I can tell, but you can do one of the following:

1. Download a big dictionary from the Internet (it'll come as just a text file), then ship it as a part of your application.
2. Hit a web service that has a dictionary on the server side to look for matches.

Comment: I'll look into this. Probably better to do it locally so does not require network access. thank you.

Comment: Note that you can also do a combinational approach - have a small dictionary locally, and a large one in the cloud.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that you can ship your app with a ZIPPED version of the dictionary, and unzip it on first load. This will keep the download size small enough to not require WiFi.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Do you know of any good dictionary that I can use?

Comment: Also worth noting is that if the dictionary is simply a list of words without definitions, even a comprehensive list won't be all that large.

Answer (score 1):

I made an open source class called [CDWordList](https://github.com/cncool/CDWordList) which loads in a text file containing a list of words. You can see if a string is a word by calling -(BOOL)isWord:(NSString*)word on the object. The project comes with the English Open Word List (EOWL) which has about 128 thousand words.

Answer (score 0):

I've published a static library called [Lexicontext](http://www.lexicontext.com) some time ago, which I think is relevant if you want to pursue the offline option (it's based on WordNet).

Answer (score 0):

Old thread I know but UITextChecker does the first part without downloading wordlists:

```
-(BOOL)isDictionaryWord:(NSString*) word {
    UITextChecker *checker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
    NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *currentLanguage = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [word length]);    
    NSRange misspelledRange = [checker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:[word lowercaseString] range: searchRange startingAt:0 wrap:NO language: currentLanguage ];
return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound;
}
```

Got this from the stackoverflow link here:
[iPhone objective-c: detecting a 'real' word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861161/iphone-objective-c-detecting-a-real-word/6861260#6861260)

I've tweaked the link code to change the string to lowercase, otherwise it always return a True for capital letters for some reason