# Accessing iPhone built-in dictionary or spell checker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In a game I have a text field where a user can enter a word. Now I'm trying to find a way to check whether the entered word is actually a word.

Do you know if there is an interface to access the built-in dictionary? Or any other ideas apart from building my own word lists?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861161/iphone-objective-c-detecting-a-real-word/6861260#6861260 See there for an implementation.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Can you post this comment as an answer? I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @Matt:whats wrong with my answer?

Comment: Nothing but the link he posted contains the code already written while your answer is a hint. So the link he posted is more useful. I gave you a vote, don't worry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate of [iPhone objective-c: detecting a 'real' word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861161/iphone-objective-c-detecting-a-real-word/6861260#6861260), code posted by user [brain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497339/brain):

```
-(BOOL)isDictionaryWord:(NSString*)word {
    UITextChecker *checker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
    NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *currentLanguage = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [word size]];

    NSRange misspelledRange = [checker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:word range: searchRange startingAt:0 wrap:NO language: currentLanguage ];
    return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess [UITextChecker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what u looking for. You can use its `rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:range:startingAt:wrap:language:` method to detect whether entered string is a word or not.