# Lookup from dictionary- objective-c

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In this app I'm building, I'm hoping for the app to take a word that is given to it and search a dictionary to see whether or not the word is real. How would I go about doing this in objective-c?

Does objective-c have anything like the 'V-Lookup' function in Excel? If so, would this be useful?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For implementing a dictionary... use `NSDictionary`.

Comment: probably, you should improve your skills before you start to develop any app. if you have some knowledge of Objective-C, proceed with `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSPredicates`, blocks _KVC_, etc...

Comment: @H2CO3, that is not such dictionary, I guess he meant the word 'dictionary' as a massive collection of words like a real dictionary would have.

Comment: @holex Yes that is exactly what i meant haha can be confusing

Comment: For the Excel-challenged programmers... What does the V-Lookup do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you're trying to do is this:

[iPhone objective-c: detecting a 'real' word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861161/iphone-objective-c-detecting-a-real-word/6861260#6861260)

```
-(BOOL)isDictionaryWord:(NSString*)word {
    UITextChecker *checker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
    NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *currentLanguage = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [word size]];

    NSRange misspelledRange = [checker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:word range: searchRange startingAt:0 wrap:NO language: currentLanguage ];
    return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound;

}
```